# Is it possible to have Google Maps hide the left panel?

Tags: google-maps

I found that just using the "ll" and "z" parameters are enough to zoom in on an area, but I couldn't find how/if Google can be told to hide the left panel ("Get Directions", "My Places", etc.) so that users see a full map when visiting a URL:

http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=54.868705,-1.593018&z=9

Is there a way?

Comment: I’m using the Google Maps app. As far as I can see, there is NO WAY to close the side panel and still maintain a useable pin or marker! The side panel takes up about a third of my iPad screen. I’m deleting the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `output=embed` to the URL will hide the left panel and search bar:

http://maps.google.com/maps?output=embed&ll=54.868705,-1.593018&z=9

However, this is intended to be used for embedding purposes. As such, there is no way to reopen the left panel or search bar in the resulting map.

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: Doesn't or maybe no longer works, the result page says: The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe.

Comment: It works from an iframe `<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?output=embed&ll=54.868705,-1.593018&z=9"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

The huge left side panel gets in my way but you can work around it:

1. open new Google Maps page
2. instead of searching, just scroll the map up or down to the desired state
3. once in the target state, zoom in a bit and locate your city
4. work your way down from there

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the search panel, uncheck 'Update results when map moves'. Stops the search panel from popping open when zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Try the URL as such.
https://www.google.com/maps/@41.8333925,-88.0123393,10z/data=!5m1!1e1

It still has the search box in the upper left of the map.
But the whole left side panel is not there.
If you need the panel back, you can click on the options icon with the search box.